# Variable names must not start with 'm_' : StyleCop Rule 1308 - Why is it considered a bad (or not good/standard) practice?

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring, naming-conventions, stylecop

I have started using the StyleCop and it gives warning wherever there is a variable declared like `m_VariableName`.

The warning message is : `Variable names must not start with 'm_'`. This is StyleCop rule `SA1308`.

I can turn this rule off. But

1) I would like to know why is it a bad practice or considered to be a bad practice to declare variable names starting with 'm_'?

2) Does the underscore character has a special meaning for Visual Studio refactoring? (I heard it from one of the senior developers.)

Comment: Please don't use C++ naming for C#. I happen to like the StyleCop rule. ALL_CAPs _myInstance, and m_MyVar are horrible. Names should describe the object, not the properties of it, let the keywords do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default StyleCop rules follow the [Microsoft C# coding style](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/f75d6cb4-084f-4f2a-95c0-6d7f1b67c978).

These include not using `m_` as a prefix (seen as [Hungarian Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation)).

If your team does not follow these style guidelines and has your own, feel free to switch the rule off.

Answer (score 6):

It just matches Microsoft's [naming guidelines for Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx):

> Do not use a prefix for field names. For example, do not use g_ or s_ to distinguish static versus non-static fields.

I believe it was part of the general purge of Hungarian that Microsoft attempted to implement when they introduced .NET.

But as with all things around coding style, if it doesn't fit what you and/or your team are comfortable with, then don't use it.

Comment: +1 BUT I already accepted another response as answer. So I cannot accept yours too, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's a bad practice - personally I prefer typing and reading `m_banana` than `this.banana`. StyleCop has some default coding *conventions* to check, and if you don't like them, or are already using other conventions, turn the warnings off or write your custom rules.

Comment: +1 BUT I already accepted another response as answer. So I cannot accept yours too, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure about this, but some developers tend to prefix object fields' names with m_. If you open up reflector, you will see that it's a common practice into Microsoft's code.

Lots of books also contain examples like that.

Now, why is that a bad practice... No idea :)
I personally don't do that and always prefix fields with the `this` keyword.